# IF condition in INNER JOIN SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in writing sql query. Here is the illustration about my problem.
I have 2 tables in the database as follows :

```
| Table A    |          | Table B     |

| idTableA   |          | idTableB    |
| idPriority |          | idReference |
```

Those tables above are related. The **idReference** in **Table B** is referring to **idPriority** in **Table A**. **BUT** if the value of the **idPriority** is **NULL**, then the **idReference** should be referring to **idTableA**. Hope you guys get the illustration and can help me working with this problem. Thx in advance.

Comment: thx guys. i got the idea to solve this from your answers. thx a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Double-join method, easy to read**

```
select
  B.idTableB,
  isnull(A1.idPriority, A2.idTableA) as RefValue
from
  TableB as B
  left join TableA as A1 on A1.idPriority = B.idReference
  left join TableA as A2 on A1.idTableA = B.idReference
```

**Single-join method, two IsNulls()'s:**

```
select
  B.idTableB,
  isnull(A1.idPriority, A1.idTableA) as RefValue
from
  TableB as B
  left join TableA as A1 on isnull(A1.idPriority, A1.idTableA) = B.idReference
```

Answer (score 1):

would the following construct work for you?

```
select *
from tableA join tableB on (join condition)
where (idpriority is not null)
union
select *
from tableA join tableB on (join condition)
where (idpriority is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tableB b 

join tableA a 
on
    a.idPriority = b.idReference
    or
    (a.idPriority IS NULL AND b.idReference = a.idTableA)
```